# Unable to get the list of topics from AWS MSK using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

we are trying to get the list of topics using the Python, but it returns empty list.

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient

#configure Kafka client for SCRAM

client = KafkaAdminClient(
bootstrap_servers="b-2-public.url.url2.c3.kafka.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:9196",
sasl_mechanism="SCRAM-SHA-512",
sasl_plain_username="user",
sasl_plain_password="pass",
security_protocol="SASL_SSL")

topics = client.list_topics()

print(topics)
```

we are able to retrieve the list of topis using the Java but for some reason not in Python.
we are using python 3.7, kafka-python 2.0.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct region?

Comment: @brushtakopo in a connection string or in .aws/credentials file? I would expect any kind of connection timeout error if the code will not be able to establish a connection